# Next.JS matching routes without leading unique keyword

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using next.js and I'm facing the follow issue:
I have

```
domain.com/{tag_name} that has pages/tag/[...slug], 
domain.com/{location_name} that has pages/locations/[...slug]
domain.com/{landing_page_name} that has **pages/landing_pages/[...slug]
```

How I can capture all of them when I don't have a unique key to match them?

Let's say I have the follow real life links :

```
 domain.com/awesome , something-else-that-user-can-input- tag 
 domain.com/visit-sofia,  something-else-that-user-can-input -  landing page 
 domain.com/sofia,  something-else-that-user-can-input -  location page
```

My current routes are

```
 async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:slug/things-to-do/:action",
        destination: "/activity/:slug/things-to-do/:action",
      },
      {
        source: "/things-to-do/:action",
        destination: "/activity/things-to-do/:action",
      },
      {
        source: "/:slug/stay/:action",
        destination: "/accommodation/:slug/stay/:action",
      },
      {
        source: "/packages/:slug",
        destination: "/package/:slug",
      },
      {
        source: "/:slug",
        destination: "/location/:slug",
      },
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/home",
      },
    ];
  },
```

Comment: Ok, you can create 3 folders (`tag`, `location` and `landing_pages`) and in them can create a new file `[…params].js` , so it should match url with any segments followerd by the folder name.

Comment: How I can manage the route file? 
Let's say I have the follow real life links : 
domain.com/awesome , something-else-that-user-can-input- tag 
domain.com/visit-sofia,  something-else-that-user-can-input -  landing page domain.com/sofia,  something-else-that-user-can-input -  location page